# simple permutation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I trying to compute a simple probability but I am not sure whether the calculation is correct.

Suppose we have 32 distinct balls. We pick 8 balls uniformly at random w/o replacement and keep them in Bag1. Independently, we repeat the same process from the beginning and keep 8 balls in Bag2. I am trying to find the probability that exactly one ball is same in Bag1 and Bag2.

For a fix b1, the probability that b1 appears in Bag1 and Bag2 =$\frac{{31 \choose 7}\cdot {(31-7) \choose 7}}{{32 \choose 8}\cdot {32 \choose 8}}$. Since we can fix any one of the 32 balls, required probability is 32 times the above quantity.

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: Did you read the post about "maths habits"?

Comment: Yes, this calculation is correct.